# Time input by user

Tags: javascript

I want to prompt a user to input a time between say 6am and 9am and then between 5 and 8 pm. I get the appropriate prompt but I don't know how to distinguish it from am or pm?

```
var time=prompt("What time is it? ","");
if(time >=6 && time <=9)
```

Comment: You could ask the user to first provide the am time and then the pm time. Or you could require them to provide "am" and "pm" as part of the input.

Comment: Your text should mention `AM/PM`..

Answer (score 0):

One way to distinguish between AM and PM is to use a 24 hour clock.

With a 24 hour clock the PM values are greater than `12`. For example `18`.

You can then subtract 12 from that value `if>12` to get the non-24 hour version. For example: `18 - 12` is 6PM

Comment: What is the times vary from over am and pm? so 11am to 2 pm?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You can ask for 24 hour time:

```js
var prompt = prompt("What time is it?", "24 hour time only");
prompt = prompt.replace(":", "");//replaces : in 9:25
prompt = parseInt(prompt);//get the integer part of prompt
if (prompt > 6 && prompt < 9 || (prompt > 600 && prompt < 900)) {//between 6-9 am
  //do something
}
else if (prompt > 17 && prompt < 20 || (prompt > 1700 && prompt < 2000)) {//between 5-8 pm
  //do something
}
else {//neither
  //do something
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Check if it ends with "am" or "pm":

```js
var prompt = prompt("What time is it?", "8am");
prompt = prompt.replace(":","");//replaces : in 9:25am
if (prompt.substr(-2,2) == "am") {
  var time = "am";
}
else if (prompt.substr(-2,2) == "pm") {
  var time = "pm"
}
else {
  alert('not a time');
}
prompt = parseInt(prompt);
if (prompt > 6 && prompt < 9 && time == "am" || (prompt > 600 && prompt < 900 && time == "am")) {
  alert("6-9 am");
}
else if (prompt > 5 && prompt < 8 && time == "pm" || (prompt > 500 && prompt < 800 && time == "pm")) {
  alert("5-8 pm");
}
else {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: what if i enter `"9:25 PM"` ? It's certainly a valid time

Comment: What is the times vary from over am and pm? so 11am to 2 pm? as well as any other hour entered?

Comment: Copy one of the `else if` statements and change the times.

Comment: Thats what I thought but when I did that and ran it the added alert did not run. So I thought it was something to do with the not recognizing the split between 11am and 2pm

Comment: For 12 hour time, use `(prompt > 11 && time == "am") || (prompt < 2 && time == "pm")`.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer, if it worked for you?

Comment: There is no check mark next to solution 2 otherwise I would. Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no check box next to solution 2 though. Solution 1 is the only thing I see with a checkmark.

Comment: **solution 1** and **solution 2** are added by me in the text of the answer.